# Create a dataframe based on another dataframe using unique values

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a Pandas dataframe like so:

```
colA colB
 A    A1
 B    C1
 A    B1
 B    A1
```

colA has 2 unique values (A, B) and colB has 3 unique values (A1, B1 and C1).

I would like to create a new dataframe where colA and colB are all combinations and another column colC which is 1 or 0 based on the combination present in earlier df.

expected result:

```
colA colB colC
 A    A1   1
 A    B1   1
 A    C1   0
 B    A1   1
 B    B1   0
 B    C1   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) filled by `1`, then create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) by [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of both columns and after [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - there is possible set value for new appended rows in `colC` column by `fill_value` parameter:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['colA'].unique(),
                                  df['colB'].unique()], names=['colA','colB'])
df1 = df.assign(colC = 1).set_index(['colA','colB']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df1)
  colA  colB  colC
0      A  A1     1
1      A  C1     0
2      A  B1     1
3      B  A1     1
4      B  C1     1
5      B  B1     0
```

Alternative is use reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(colC = 1)
         .set_index(['colA','colB'])['colC']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='ColC'))

print (df1)
  colA colB  ColC
0    A   A1     1
1    A   B1     1
2    A   C1     0
3    B   A1     1
4    B   B1     0
5    B   C1     1
```

Another solution is create new `DataFrame` by [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True`, rename column and set by compare by `both` and casting to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
from  itertools import product
df1 = pd.DataFrame(product(df['colA'].unique(), df['colB'].unique()), columns=['colA','colB'])
df = df1.merge(df, how='left', indicator=True).rename(columns={'_merge':'colC'})
df['colC'] = df['colC'].eq('both').astype(int)
print (df)
  colA colB  colC
0    A   A1     1
1    A   C1     0
2    A   B1     1
3    B   A1     1
4    B   C1     1
5    B   B1     0
```

---

Last if necessary add sorting by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['colA','colB'])
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation for what you're doing, especially for the assign() line?

Comment: @FedericoS - Done :)